# Description of all layers in a QGIS project

Tags: qgis, layers, mapinfo

Is there a way to view the properties of each layer (especially Route and CRS) of a project, all together in a list? (I am using QGIS 3.8.3)

The same way that in the Project Properties > Source of data, one can see the list of all layers in the project it would be very useful if next to the layer name one could see its properties.

Project properties:

[image: Project properties example]

Layer properties:

[image: Layer properties example]

This worked very well with MapInfo workspace, a list of all the tables (layers) and its settings that were being used.